# Check values of nested items of object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check the week object's minutes and hours and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. The week object can contain variations of Day1 - Day7 so I dont want to check them specifically. I want to check the nested Hours/Minutes. I also don't want to use jquery and it has to work with ie8. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
week = {
        Day1: {
            Hours: 6,
            Minutes: 20
        },
        Day2: {
            Minutes: 45
        },
        Day3: {
            Hours: 8,
            Minutes: 15
        }
    };

hoursInValid = false;
minutesInValid = false;

for (var item in week) {
        if (week.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < week[item].length; i++ )
            {
                if (week[item][i].Hours > 6) {
                    hoursInValid = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (week[item][i].Minutes > 20) {
                    minutesInValid = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So in your example I believe i = `Hours` or `Minutes` so you don't need the `.Hours` or `.Minutes` in your expressions.

Comment: I believe the inner loop needs to be a `for (key in var`), like the outer loop.

Comment: Objects don`t have a length property in JavaScript, use another `for(var key in Object)` loop.

Comment: Good call. I don't do for..in loops much in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for the internal `for` loop. This is the solution I came up with. I added checks to make sure the `DayN` objects have `Hours` and `Minutes` properties.

```
week = {
  Day1: {
    Hours: 6,
    Minutes: 20
  },
  Day2: {
    Minutes: 45
  },
  Day3: {
    Hours: 8,
    Minutes: 15
  }
};

hoursInValid = false;
minutesInValid = false;

for (var item in week) {
  if (week[item].hasOwnProperty('Hours')) {
    if (week[item].Hours > 6) {
      hoursInValid = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (week[item].hasOwnProperty('Minutes')) {
    if (week[item].Minutes > 20) {
      minutesInValid = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
var invalidHours = {}, invalidMinutes = {};
for(var i in week){
  var w = week[i];
  if(w.hasOwnProperty('Hours')){
    invalidHours[i] = w.Hours > 6 ? true : false;
  }
  else{
    // no hours
  }
  if(w.hasOwnProperty('Minutes')){
    invalidMinutes[i] = w.Minutes > 20 ? true : false;
  }
  else{
    // no minutes
  }
}
if(invalidHours.Day1) // day 1 hours are invalid
if(invalidMinutes.Day2) // day 2 minutes are invalid
```

Comment: Still doesn't `item` = `Day1` and therefore `i` = `Hours`? Why do you need the `.Hours` after `week[item][i]`?

Comment: @Leeish You are correct. The above code does not work.

Comment: `for ... in` iterates over the properties on an object, so while this solution "technically" works, the `if (week.hasOwnProperty(item))` is completely unnecessary. In addition, this code will fail if the `DayN` objects have either no `Hours` or `Minutes` property. Both my solution and the solution by @Joseph Ahn account for this last issue.

Comment: @JohnnyEstilles I will take a closer look. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (var day in week) {
    for (var unit in week[day]) {
        if (unit === 'Hours' && week[day][unit] > 6) {
            hoursInvalid = true;
        } else if (unit === 'Minutes' && week[day][unit] > 20) {
            minutesInvalid = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The break statements may not allow you to iterate over all the properties.

Comment: I only want to iterate for an hour until it fails and for a minute until it fails